# Does the geofencing setting/configuration should be done from the activity class or can it be done using Service class?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-pendingintent, geofencing, android-geofence

I went through geofencing documentation from android and few other examples on web. Common on all of them is, the initialize Geofencing client from an activity, and add geofence and assign pending intent on the activity itself. On in the pending intent they pass Intent service class or the Broadcast receiver class. My first question

1. If I initialize a class in an activity lets say "GeofenceActivity" and then I close the app (press back button also remove it from recently used application), will the Intent service or Broadcast receiver class that were passed in Pending intent will still be able to get the event notification of enter and exist ?
2. Can I initialize the class in the service class, and prepare pending intent in this class ?

What my need is, I want to setup environment is such a way that even when the app is not working (By app I mean UI, service will be running), I want to notified about geofence event.

```
Service class:
package com.services;


import android.Manifest;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofenceStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import receiver.GeofenceBroadcastReceiver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {

    static MediaPlayer mp;

    private static final String GEO_PENDING_KEY = "MMW-GEOFENCING-KEY";
    private static PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;
    private static LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    public static GeofencingClient GEOFENCING_CLIENT;
    private static Context geocontext;
    private static CountDownTimer timer;
    private static double latitude, longitude;
    private static float radius;
    private static ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;

    private static final String IDENTIFIER = "LocationAlertIS";
    int geofenceTransition;
    private static final int JOB_ID = 573;
    //private static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";
    private static final String TAG = "Ganesh";
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: GEO FENCING STARTED");
        SetTimerStatus(true);
        PrepareGeoClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy: GEO FENCING DESTROYED XXXX");
        SetTimerStatus(false);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "ENQUING FIRST PHASE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        enqueueWork(context, GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService.class, JOB_ID, intent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(geocontext, "ENQUING FINAL PHASE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }catch (Exception ex){

                }
            }
        });


        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            Log.e(IDENTIFIER, "" + getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode()));
            return;
        }

        Log.i(IDENTIFIER, geofencingEvent.toString());

        geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            //logic to process geofence event
        }
    }

    private String getGeofenceTransitionInfo(List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
        ArrayList<String> locationNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
            locationNames.add(getLocationName(geofence.getRequestId()));
            System.out.println("GET LOACTION NAME");
        }
        String triggeringLocationsString = TextUtils.join(", ", locationNames);

        return triggeringLocationsString;
    }

    private String getLocationName(String key) {
        String[] strs = key.split("-");

        String locationName = null;
        if (strs != null && strs.length == 2) {
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(strs[0]);
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(strs[1]);
            locationName = getLocationNameGeocoder(lat, lng);
        } else System.out.println("NULLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL");
        if (locationName != null) {
            return locationName;
        } else {
            return key;
        }
    }

    private String getLocationNameGeocoder(double lat, double lng) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        } catch (Exception ioException) {
            Log.e("", "Error in getting location name for the location");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error in getting location name for the location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
            Log.d("", "no location name");
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Location name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return null;
        } else {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            ArrayList<String> addressInfo = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                addressInfo.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
            }

            return TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), addressInfo);
        }
    }

    private String getErrorString(int errorCode) {
        switch (errorCode) {
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                return "Geofence not available";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
                return "geofence too many_geofences";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
                return "geofence too many pending_intents";
            default:
                return "geofence error";
        }
    }

    private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return "location entered";
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return "location exited";
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL:
                return "dwell at location";
            default:
                return "location transition";
        }
    }

    private void notifyLocationAlert(String locTransitionType, String locationDetails) {

        // Create an Intent for the activity you want to start
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, SettingTabMainMapActivity.class);
        // Create the TaskStackBuilder and add the intent, which inflates the back stack
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
        // Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        String CHANNEL_ID = "Zoftino";
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(geocontext, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mmw_red_white_60)
                        .setContentTitle(locTransitionType)
                        .setContentText(locationDetails)
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                        .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        //Vibration
        builder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});

        //LED
        builder.setLights(Color.RED, 10000, 10000);


        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

    private void triggerDetection() {
        Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
        Intent intent = new Intent("trigger-detection");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra("clear", "This is my message6!");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void triggerGeofence(double lat, double longs) {

        Patient patient = (Patient) MedWatchApp.getCurrentUser();

        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

           //alert geofence exit
        }

        else if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {

        //alert geofence entrance
    }

    static void SetTimerStatus(boolean start){
        try{
            if(!start) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }
            else{
                if(timer==null){
                    timer = new CountDownTimer(3600000, 5000) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long l) {
                            if(GEOFENCING_CLIENT == null){
                                Log.i(TAG, "onTick: GEO CLIENT NULL");
                            }else{
                                Log.i(TAG, "onTick: OK GEO CLIENT NOT NULL");
                            }
                            if(geocontext == null){
                                Log.i(TAG, "onTick: CONTEXT NULLLL");
                            }else{
                                Log.i(TAG, "onTick: CONTEXT FINE");
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {

                        }
                    };
                    timer.start();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){

        }
    }

    public static void SetGeofenceClient(GeofencingClient client){
        GEOFENCING_CLIENT = client;
    }

    public static void ResetGeofenceClient(){
        GEOFENCING_CLIENT = null;
    }
    public static GeofencingClient GetGeofenceingClient(){
        return GEOFENCING_CLIENT;
//        return  null;
    }
    public static void SetGeoContext(Context context){
        geocontext = context;
    }

    private static void PrepareGeoClient(){
        if(GEOFENCING_CLIENT==null){
            mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<>();
            PrepareAllGeoCoordinate(-33.8502747,151.032907,20);
            PrepareAllGeoCoordinate(-33.8502747,151.029999,20);
            PrepareAllGeoCoordinate(-33.8492767,151.0328641,20);
            PrepareAllGeoCoordinate(-33.8499534,151.0297315,10);
            PrepareAllGeoCoordinate(-33.8500069,151.0297422,10);
            PrepareAllGeoCoordinate(-33.8500247,151.0297529,10);
            GEOFENCING_CLIENT = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(geocontext);
            //createLocationRequest();
            RemoveGeoLocations();
        }
        AddGeoLocation();
    }

    //specifications of real location updates.
    protected static void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(2000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    protected static void RemoveGeoLocations(){
        GEOFENCING_CLIENT.removeGeofences(getGeofencePendingIntent()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(geocontext, "REMOVED>>>", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(geocontext, "FALED REMOVED>>>", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

protected static void AddGeoLocation(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(geocontext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    GEOFENCING_CLIENT.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(geocontext,
                                "Location alter has been added",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(geocontext,
                                "Geofence could not be added",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
//geofence triggering alert process
private static PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(geocontext, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(geocontext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
}
//geofence triggering alert process
private static GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest(Geofence geofence) {
    // The INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER flag indicates that geofencing service should trigger a
    // GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER notification when the geofence is added and if the device
    // is already inside that geofence.
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    // builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofence(geofence);
//        builder.setInitialTrigger(4);



    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

//geofence triggering alert process
private static GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        // The INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER flag indicates that geofencing service should trigger a
        // GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER notification when the geofence is added and if the device
        // is already inside that geofence.
//        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER |GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL);
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
        return builder.build();
    }
public static void SetGeoParams(double lat, double lng, float rad){
        latitude = lat;
        longitude = lng;
        radius = rad;
    }

private static void PrepareAllGeoCoordinate(double lat, double lng, int rad){
    //Create dummy data for testing
            mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId(String.format("%f-%f",lat,lng))
                    .setCircularRegion(
                            lat,
                            lng,
                            rad
                    )
                    .setLoiteringDelay(60000)
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL)

                    // Create the geofence.
                    .build());
            //
        }
    }


    I set the context from MainActivity calling following method in onCreate method:
    void PrepareGeoFence(){
    //        -33.8502747,151.032907
            GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService.SetGeoContext(this);
            GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService.SetGeoParams(-33.8502747,
    //                151.029999
                    151.032907,
                    10f);
    this.startService(new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService.class));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. yes it will - even if process of your application is killed, then Broadcast receiver handle will make it alive and from there you can start working with the event
2. it does not matter from what Android component you create geofence